# SQL compare values in double select

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have 2 tables, in one are stored bus lines and in other stations for those lines.
So I made a search option and I'm trying do display only buses that go from point A(Starting Point) to point B(Destination).
Here is my code:

```
SELECT BusName FROM Buses 
WHERE BusID IN 
(SELECT BusID FROM Stations WHERE StationName = @StartingPoint AND BusID IN 
(SELECT BusID FROM Stations WHERE (StationName = @Destination)))
```

The problem is that it displays buses that go from point B to point A.
I have column StationNum which is used for route order i.e. A = 10 and B = 255. So is there any easy way I could compare StationNum from third select with StationNum from first select?

Comment: How about switching the two select clauses?
That first you say WHERE StationName = Destination and in the 2nd "BusID IN..." you say WHERE StationName = StartingPoint

Comment: @Trickzter That wouldn't change anything. To explain my problem better, there could be stations C and D in between A and B, and the only way to know the route is to compare StationNum of C and D, and if C has smaller StationNum and is equal to StartingPoint it should be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use derived tables and do joins on them like the following:

```
SELECT B.BusName
FROM Buses B INNER JOIN
(SELECT BusID, StationName FROM Stations WHERE StationName = @StartingPoint) BS ON B.BusID = BS.BusID INNER JOIN
(SELECT BusID, StationName FROM Stations WHERE (StationName = @Destination) BD ON B.BusID = BD.BusID
 WHERE BS.StationName > BD.StationName
```

You now have the ability to reference the station name for the starting point and the station name for the destinations and do a comparison in the WHERE clause.